# How to check the reason of the woocommerce error?

Tags: wordpress

I just clean malware from my site. When I try to up the website, the error appeared. May I know the reason why the error happen? How to check the caused of the error?

[image]

This is the code mention in the error

```html
add_filter( ¡®woocommerce_product_tabs¡¯, ¡®sb_woo_remove_reviews_tab¡¯, 98);

function sb_woo_remove_reviews_tab($tabs) { unset($tabs[¡®reviews¡¯]);

return $tabs;}
```

Comment: Go to the location of the file and look at the code, verify if there's anything wrong with them.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to hide notice errors in your case.

Hide the notices by modifying wp-config.php : "define('WP_DEBUG', false);". The value was "true" instead of "false".

Comment: The value is true in the config file